# How to return the concrete Product type from my function?

Tags: scala

I have different product types like:

```
sealed trait Product
case class Downloadable(url: String) extends Product
case class Shippable(weight: Int) extends Product
case class Virtual(name: String) extends Product

object Load {
  def get(id: Int): Product = id match {
    case 1 => Downloadable("google.com")
    case 2 => Shippable(100)
    case _ => Virtual("virtuallll")
  }
}

println(Load.get(1))
println(Load.get(2))
println(Load.get(3))

val d = Load.get(1)
println(d.url)  // error value url is not a member
```

I don't have access to the properties of the concrete type, is it possible to be able to?

Comment: Do you expect to always call the method using a compile-time constant? Otherwise, this wouldn't work because the compiler can't travel in time to see all the possibilities in all the multi-verses to infer which will be the right choice.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching.

```
Load.get(1) match {
  case dl:Downloadable => println(s"URL: ${dl.url}")
  case shp:Shippable   => println(s"weight: ${shp.weight}")
  case vt:Virtual      => println(s"name: ${vt.name}")
}
```

Each variable (`dl`, `shp`, `vt`) exists only within its `case` code block.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to deal uniformly with instances that are not uniform. The solution is to make them uniform, that's what base classes and traits are for: defining and describing common interface.

```
sealed trait Product[T] { def data: T }
case class Downloadable(url: String) extends Product[String] { def data = url }
case class Shippable(weight: Int) extends Product[Int] { def data = weight }
case class Virtual(name: String) extends Product[String] { def data = name }
```

then you can do `println(Product.get(1).data)`

Alternatively (and I don't really recommend that, but if it is like the only place in the codebase where you need this, implementing it properly is too complicated) you can exploit the fact that case classes are instances of `Product` (not *your* Product, but [scala library trait](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Product.html) representing a cartesian product).
All `Product` instances have a method `productIterator` that lets you iterate through values of all member variables. So, you can just do this with your existing definitions:

```
    println(Product.load(1).productIterator.next)
```